# How to keep updating textview with the location accuracy from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, location, handler, ui-thread

I would like to update the users' location accuracy every 2 seconds.

I have created this function `getAccuracy(activity, currentAccuracy)` that updates the textView with the current location whenever it is called.

I would like it to be called every 2 seconds. This is my current code but it doesn't work - the text doesn't get a value even once and stays blank, where if I use the function without the runOnUiThread it will show at least once.

```
    val activity = activity as CameraActivity


    val handler = Handler()
    val delay: Long = 2000 //milliseconds

    handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {

            activity.runOnUiThread {
                object : Runnable {
                    override fun run() {
                        getAccuracy(activity, currentAccuracy)
                    }
                }
            }

            handler.postDelayed(this, delay)
        }
    }, delay)
```

This is the function, using the [AirLocation](https://github.com/mumayank/AirLocation) library

```
fun getAccuracy(activity: Activity, currentAccuracy: TextView) {

    airLocation = AirLocation(activity, true, true, object : AirLocation.Callbacks {
        override fun onSuccess(location: Location) {
            currentAccuracy.text = location.accuracy.toString()
            Log.d("locationAccuracy","Success")
        }

        override fun onFailed(locationFailedEnum: AirLocation.LocationFailedEnum) {
            Log.d("locationAccuracy","Fail")

        }

    })

}
```

Comment: You need to describe what you mean by "doesn't work" and add a bit more context (or code) to the question. It's hard to help you in the current state of the question

Comment: @Leo appreciate the feedback. I've updated it with more info

Comment: It'd be good if you add some logging to the `onSuccess` and `onFailed` callback functions to make sure that `AirLocation` is not failing and if it is failing, then find out why through the `AirLocation.LocationFailedEnum` object

Comment: I've added two logs, updated the code in my question. None of them show's up so the function is never called.
I've never used a handler or the runOnUiThread call so I'm probably nor using one of them right, but not sure which or how to fix.

Comment: @Tsabary, Are you sure you have followed each step in this  https://github.com/mumayank/AirLocation

Comment: @Nil thank you Nil. I am able to get the location using the library, my issue is updating the ui with the most recent accuracy every 2 seconds

Comment: Use a recursive(call getLocation function onSuccess callback)You'll get as much as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-creating the `AirLocation` instance every 2 seconds which is not good because it probably won't have enough time to even get location data. You should use the same instance. To fix the issue...

You should make the `airLocation` variable a private member variable of the class. I think you've already done that...

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var airLocation: AirLocation? = null
}
```

Then initialize that variable in `onCreate`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        airLocation = AirLocation(this, true, true, object: AirLocation.Callbacks {
                override fun onSuccess(location: Location) {
                    if(location != null){
                        currentAccuracy.text = location.accuracy.toString()
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailed(locationFailedEnum: AirLocation.LocationFailedEnum) {
                }

            })
}
```

Then override the `onActivityResult` and call the `AirLocation`'s `onActivityResult`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        airLocation?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

That should work assuming you are handling the required permissions and location settings are on. 
Unfortunately this library doesn't allow you set the interval between location requests, the interval is set to 10 seconds with the fastest interval to 2 seconds, you can't change that. Here's a snippet of the source code...

```
val locationRequest = LocationRequest().apply {
        interval = 10000
        fastestInterval = 2000
        priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        numUpdates = 1
    }
```

However, if it is crucial for you to be in control of the intervals, you can build your own implementation. It's not that hard. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the answer Leo. One thing that I am missing though is where do I set the textview text? What I am trying to achieve is show the user the live accuracy of their device, and have it keep updating. 2 seconds is alright for me. This is where I get lost and why I tried to use a handler and runOnTheUiThred

Comment: @Tsabary in `onSuccess`...I just added it to the answer

Comment: This is how I had it originally (prior to trying the handler and other methods). It works just fine at setting the text but it sets it once and never updates before. I tried to walk around with my device outside and even a minute later it remained the same down to 3 digits after the point (It was 16.377 and remained). Do I need to call that location request snippet you've added somehow or is that just an automated thing in the background?

Comment: That probably have to do with `numUpdates` set to `1`. Because you can't override it, I'd suggest implement your own...remove that library from your project and create the `AirLocation` class...here's the source code https://github.com/mumayank/AirLocation/blob/master/airlocationlibrary/src/main/java/mumayank/com/airlocationlibrary/AirLocation.kt

Comment: Working on doing that. Thank you.